# How to share instance the same instance in multiple Maven plugin Mojos?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm implementing Maven plugin that starts and stops in-memory database server. I have two Mojos `ServerStart` and `ServerStop`. In the `ServerStop` I create an instance of database server and start it calling `server.start()`. In `ServerStop` Mojo I'd like to get the same instance of a server to call `server.stop()`. Can I somehow create instance of Server and then have it injected into my Mojos?

Here is the sample code:

```
@MojoGoal("start")
public class StartServerMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    //How to instantiate and inject the server here?
    private Server server;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    server.start();
    }

}

@MojoGoal("stop")
public class StopServerMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    //How to instantiate and inject the server here?
    private Server server;

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
    server.stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: 2 questions. 1) How do you want to inject it into your mojos? E.g., do you have it somewhere configured? 2) I haven't seen such annotation (`@MojoGoal("stop")`) before. Can you show me where did you find it? :)

Comment: Andrew, I don't have it configured. That's my question, how to instantiate it and have injected. The annotations are from JFrog's Maven Anno Mojo extension (http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/OSS/Maven+Anno+Mojo). It allows to use Java annotations instead of XDoclet annotations.

Comment: Ok, I see. What do you need to do to instantiate a server? I mean programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

you can define server link this

```
/**
 * @parameter
 * */
private Server server;
```

and configure it in the pom where you quoted the plugin

like:

```
<configuration>
<server>
 <serverField1>value1</serverField1>
 <serverField2>value2</serverField2>
 ...
</server>
</configuration>
```

see here:http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep the server instance in pluginContext available at AbtractMojo. Just remember that you can't access it from failsafe tests.

Another approach would be turning your plugin in form of a container for Cargo maven plugin in similar manner that I did with OSGi framework (https://github.com/TuomasKiviaho/org.codehause.cargo.container.osgi). The Cargo project is aimed for testing against JavaEE containers but that wasn't a problem for me.